# How do I cut something in the game engine?

Tags: game-engine

I have a sword attached to a model who swings it every time the mouse is clicked. I would like to know if there is a way the sword could slice though things when it hits them.
Is there a way i could limit this to certain objects? That way he wouldn't cut though solid steel.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could have the game engine replace the "solid" model with a model representing the "broken" model. Not the best method for realism, but it would work every time :)

[image]

Comment: Yeah but I want the cut to appear where the sword swings. if I clobber that cube on the right side and the left bursts into flame and dies, it kinda loses the effect of cutting.

Comment: @VinceScalia that sounds like something that would require scripting if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Okay by me. do you have an idea for a script/?

Comment: there are some tools like Grease cutter and Bisect that may help with this.  You would be in somewhat uncharted areas doing this in a game however and these tools may not even be accessible in the BGE side of things. The IRC channel  and #blenderpython may be a good place for you to discuss these things with other people.  Also there is #blendercoders but that's more for C/C++ coders who develop for Blender rather than user support.  http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?316520-Sculpt-Tools and also  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G2CdYFgrP84