# Make modifiers update in the game engine

Tags: python, game-engine, modifiers, logic-bricks

I am trying to make a boat work in the game engine, and I have a *Boolean* modifier on the water cutting a spot in the water plane for the boat. The problem is, that when the boat moves, and the mesh that cuts the spot moves with it, the spot cut out in the water plane remained where it was before. Is there any way to make the *Boolean* modifier update live in the game engine via python? I have looked for a while and there is no possible way to do this with logic bricks alone. The end result would be the boat moves, and the collision mesh moves with it, and the collision mesh cuts the spot in the water for the boat as it moves along.

[image]

Comment: AFAIK this is just not supported..

Comment: Why do you need modifiers in the game engine?

Comment: @X-27 Nah, I could be wrong. And even it it is impossible, a negative answer would be better.

Comment: See also [this question](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/20858/how-do-i-cut-something-in-the-game-engine).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I've done for similar situations:

Parent the water (object plane watter?) to the boat collision mesh.

Add the rest of the water outside the two.

Make a surf animation in the water enclosing the boat so that it roils up in front, but only when the boat moves.

Now when the boat moves, the hole moves with it. Brilliant huh?

Comment: I see. were you going to use the special game water shader?